# TYPO3 404 error page redirect to home page

Tags: php, typo3, http-status-code-404, realurl

TYPO3 redirects to home page instead of showing 404 error page content.

Here is my configuration :

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getIndpEnv('TYPO3_SITE_URL') . 'error-404';
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling_statheader'] = $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found';
```

If I visit http://example.com/index.php?id=33333 (which is a non-existing page) it works fine. But if I visit http://example.com/sdafsdfasdfpi (which is also a non-existing page), it redirects me to the home page.

Does someone know how to fix that?

Thanks

Comment: Is EXT:realurl installed?

Comment: Yes it is installed.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment by Heinz Schilling indicates, the problem *may* be in your **realurl** configuration.

Check your typo3conf/realurl_conf.php for **postVarSet_failureMode** :

`$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl'][...]['init']['postVarSet_failureMode']`

It should be assigned with an empty string. If the value is 'postVarSet_failureMode' => 'redirect_goodUpperDir' then the behavour is to redirect to the start page, so that *may* be the reason.

Additionally, it might be helpful to post your realurl configuration as well as your TYPO3 version and realurl version number.

Answer (score 0):

In your `LocalConfiguration.php` file add below line. check php function `curl` is enable or not in your php.ini file. if curl is disable then first enable this function..

```
'FE' => [
   'pageNotFound_handling' => 'error-404' // Set your error page
],
```